# Custom Django Rest Framework Serializer Field not running `to_representation()` if value is null

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I would like a custom (read-only) serializer field that replaces the serialized value if it is `None`.  I assumed that I could just overwrite `to_representation()`, but that doesn't seem to run.  Here is some code:

**models.py:**

```
class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

**serializers:**

```
class ReplaceableSerializerField(serializers.ReadOnlyField):

  def to_representation(self, value):
    if value is None:
      return "this book sucks"
    return value

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ("title", "rating",)

  rating = ReplaceableSerializerField(allow_null=True)
```

If I then do the following:

```
hamlet = Book(title="Hamlet")
BookSerializer(instance=hamlet).data
```

I get the following response:

```
{'title': 'Hamlet', 'rating', None}
```

Notice how the rating is `None` instead of "this book sucks".

Any idea on how to force `to_representation()` to run on null fields?

Comment: Can you please do a super_call as `super().to_representation()` first in your overwriten to_representation.

Comment: @Shakil - Thanks.  That had no effect (`ReadOnlyField.to_representation()` just returns "value" anyway).

Comment: may sound stupid, can you please try value == None instead of value is None.

Comment: @Shakil - Again, this had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can understand from [implementation](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L260), `to_representation` method does not get called if the value is **None**. So to avoid this problem, I think you can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). You can use it like this:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  rating = serailizer.SerializerMethodField()

  class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ("title", "rating",)

  def get_rating(self, obj):
      if obj.rating == None:
         return "Something"
      return obj.rating
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I wound up doing.  But it still annoys me.

Comment: This is a problem because the SerializerMethodField is read-only. Usually you override the Field to get a r/w custom field, and if to_representation isn't run on null values, you can't transform null values to for example False :/

Comment: I have a use-case for this as well.  Did an issue get created for it?  If so, can you provide a link?  If not, how do "we" get that done?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to override **get_attribute(self, instance)** method.

```
def get_attribute(self, instance):
    value = getattr(instance, self.source)
    if value is None:
        return "this book sucks"
    return value
```

djangorestframework  3.12.4